# <iframe> Height responsive

Tags: html, css

So i have my page and i need  inside of it. I need that iframe to show full page content without scrollbar. That isnt a problem because its already working. The problem is how to make it responsive, so it will show full content of that iframe without scrollbar. I already made width responsive, but i cant make height to be responsive. Here is my code:

```css
.frame-area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #999999 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="Framename" src="/clients1.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="frame-area">
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

The reason why your Iframe was not going to full height was because the `html` and `body` element, were not set to `100%`, so I set this, I have used `margin:0px` to remove the default margins set by the browser. Please find below the CSS for `html` and `body` tag.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Apart from this I was also getting margins outside the Iframe this was because of the border of the IFrame which is not included in the dimensions (height and width), to overcome this, I have use the CSS property `box-sizing:border-box` which will consider the actual height including margins and borders, so the scrollbar will not be present!

```
.frame-area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #999999 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.frame-area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: #999999 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<iframe name="Framename" src="/clients1.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" class="frame-area">
</iframe>
```

Comment: @MartinĎurický Can you share the JSFiddle with the issue after implementing my code, I guess you can also do `height:100vh` and `width:100vw` for the class `frame-area`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vqzhfdca/, well i cant put whole code of html page because there is a lot of it

Comment: @MartinĎurický Is this the fix that's needed? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x81agvLe/)

Comment: No because there is scrollbar of that iframe on mobile. I need that iframe to be without scrollbar on any device so it wont look like iframe but a part of that page